# I want to align the text in a CTk Textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to align the text of my customtkinter textbox so that the text appears in the middle of the widget and not at the left side

I tried anchor and justify which both didn't work

```
self.tk_textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self.p1_show_score_frame, activate_scrollbars=False,
width=100,height=150,font=("BOLD",20),border_color="Darkblue")
self.tk_textbox.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Your example doesn't include adding text to your textbox. Can you please provide a complete [mcve]?

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/37b375d58b35d53f254d73605d5c68d38f8a5b75/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_textbox.py#L13) it looks like `CTkTextbox` doesn't accept `anchor` or `justify` arguments (they're not listed under `_valid_tk_text_attributes`, at least). You may have to subclass `CTkTextBox` and hack something together

Comment: A bit of digging later...you might be able to do this with tkinter `tags`. e.g.: `self.tk_textbox.tag_configure('center', justify='center'); self.tk_textbox.tag_add("center", 1.0, 'end')` - that said, I don't know how well or even *if* Customtkintker supports tags, so YMMV

Answer (score 1):

If you want text inside a text widget to be centered horizontally, you can apply a tag to a region of text and then configure the `justify` attribute of that tag to be `"center"`.

You can either add the tag after text has been inserted, or add the tag at the time the text is inserted. Here is an example of applying the text when the text is inserted:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
text = ctk.CTkTextbox(root, wrap="word", width=400, height=100)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.tag_config("center", justify="center")

text.insert("end", "Hello, world\nThis text should be centered horizontally\n", "center")

root.mainloop()
```